# Storing images above or below the web root?

Tags: image, upload, root, organization

I'm working on a web app where users can upload images which are associated with their account. I'm trying to figure out the best way to store these images in the filesystem taking into account organization and security. I'm using a JavaScript-based file uploader which has to save the images within the web root, but I'm wondering if it would be better to move the images above the web root for better security? Any thoughts on the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the images public or private?

Comment: They can be either, that is a user can choose to share images or not.

Answer (score 0):

From a security standpoint, you probably want to select a location where users can't see your website application images or directories when they use your image browser. So a different directory location other than your website root is a good idea. The location can be a virtual directory that points to any location on your file system, as long as you have appropriate directory security set up to read / write files through your web server.

Virtual directories can point wherever you'd like them to, and might make your backup strategies a little easier to support, if you back up all dynamic user files from time to time.

Comment: I hadn't considered virtual directories yet. I'll have to look into that. What I really want to know though, is if there is any benefit to placing uploaded images above the web root and displaying them through some sort of image controller rather than simply leaving them under the web root (for example in an uploads directory) and displaying them "naturally"

Comment: Virtual directories allow you to partition file storage on separate servers / locations. This can benefit you if you need to save lots of media to cheaper storage (i.e. if storage that doesn't require the same level of fault tolerance / recovery / speed as your DB server or web server storage may require). This would be essentially like placing "above the web root". Well, it could be. It could literally be anywhere. From an administration perspective, it could be more work to migrate your applications to new servers however. Keeping images under your web root simplifies future migration.